# Save config not working

Tags: magento-1.9, configuration

Trying to change some configurations in the magento backend however whenever I change any settings I get the message stating that it has saved however the settings remain the same.

I have cleared the cache, the issue is preventing from doing this in the magento admin area so I have done it manually.

Not entirely sure what may have caused this.